# Pimcore document tree preview not working

Tags: pimcore

When hovering over the pimcore document tree in the admin panel you get a quick preview of the documents. It's working on pimcore's admin demo page:
https://www.pimcore.org/en/resources/try

But it's not working on 2 different installations i tried, one on windows one on linux. I have seen the option "generate previews" in the document-setting, but it's alreay selected. What can be the problem? Are there other settings or do i need to install something for it?

Edit:
For the assets it's working just fine, i get the preview. But it's not working for the documents.

Answer (score 0):

You must have wkhtmltoimage installed on your system.

In Pimcore backend go to:
**Tools > System Info & Tools > System-Requirements Check**

**wkhtmltoimage** must be green.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes, it's not installed.
But how to install it? Is there a best practice how to do it?

Comment: I have found this explanation (in german, see link) and it works now on the command line but do i need to add a setting in pimcore to tell him that it's now available?
http://pimcore-hosting.de/blog/wkhtmltopdf_ubuntu_server_installieren_b3

Comment: After restarting the Server it should be directly available. Is wkhtmltoimage green now?

Comment: Yes, after using the install instructions from @Laph the wkhtmltoimage is now green. But i still don't have a preview when hovering the nodes with the mouse. Still something i have to do?

Comment: First clear temporary files. Then check the requests made to your server in developer tools. You should see a request to this URL https://yourdomain.com/admin/page/generate-screenshot. Check what is the response of that request.

Comment: Oh, now i found that menu item "Generate page previews" in the Settings/Cache submenu. Pressed it and then logged out and in again. Now it's working! Thank you!
So if i understand right those page previews on mouse hover aren't generated dynamically but only when pressing that menu button, right?

Comment: As far as I know they should be generated dynamically. Did you examine the request as I explained in my previous comment?

Comment: No, i get a load on "mydomain.com/website/var/tmp/document-page-previews/document-page-screenshot-2.jpg". And it's not dynamic. So i have to press the "generage page previews" again and clear my browsers cache to see changes.
I also tested it on the pimcore demo page. It has the same behaviour. Changes are not visible dynamically. (Though after clearing the cache it's not possible to login on their demo admin page anymore - did i mess something up?)

Comment: But anyway, as a quick preview it's fine for me if it's not dynamic. I think it's only meant to be a quick preview - so if it would be dynamic it maybe would require too much time.

Comment: After clearing the cache, the generate-screenshot should be triggered automatically. That's how it works on my installations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `wkhtmltoimage`, which comes paired with `wkhtmltopdf`.

I advise to install the Versions from [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). They are up-to-date and work right out of the box since they are statically linked. 
On a 64bit Linux box do this:

```
wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar --directory=/usr/local --strip-components=1 -xvJf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
```

Afterwards `wkhtmltoimage` and `wkhtmltopdf` are available in `/usr/local/bin` where Pimcore finds them.

Usually you don't need `xvfb` anymore with recent builds - except if you run into a [wkhtmltopdf - QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192642/wkhtmltopdf-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-display)-Error.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I have wkhtmltoimage now installed.